# How to define the return type of `getchar()`?

Tags: c

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char c;
    while((c = getchar()) != EOF) 
    {
        putchar(c);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

But some body says that i should change `char c` to `int c`.

Who can tell me the reason?

Comment: You should RTFM [getchar(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getchar.3.html) which tells you that `getchar` returns an `int`.

Answer (score 5):

Because `getchar()` is defined as:

```
 int getchar(void);
```

That should be reason enough. The reason is explained very well [here](http://c-faq.com/stdio/getcharc.html):

Two types of error/failure are possible if getchar's return value is assigned to a char.

> If type char is signed, and if EOF is defined (as is usual) as -1, the
>   character with the decimal value 255 ('\377' or '\xff' in C) will be
>   sign-extended and will compare equal to EOF, prematurely terminating
>   the input.
>
> If type char is unsigned, an actual EOF value will be truncated (by
>   having its higher-order bits discarded, probably resulting in 255 or
>   0xff) and will not be recognized as EOF, resulting in effectively
>   infinite input.

Comment: Some people might like to know _why_ `getchar` is defined to return an `int`.  Especially since I quickly looked for duplicates and couldn't find a simple "What does `getchar` return?" question.

Comment: because `getchar` just read a char and return it, why use `int` , not use `char`?

Comment: because `EOF` is not a `char` but an `int`.  So that `getchar` can either return a negative number ("I couldn't get a char!") or the next character on standard input.

Comment: @BlackMamba: see edit

Answer (score 1):

`getchar` returns `EOF` to indicate end of file or error, otherwise it returns an `unsigned char` cast to `int`. If you use `char` to store the return value you cannot tell the difference between `EOF` and some characters.